# Как загрузить файл из интернета WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, download

Я пытаюсь создать лаунчер для одной игры, и мне бы хотелось реализовать в нем функцию автоматической её загрузки.

```
webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri("https://yadi.sk/d/BvZh_cvnseoyF"), System.IO.Path.Combine(path.Text, System.IO.Path.GetFileName("zerahypt.zip")));
```

Данный вариант не работает. Вместо нужного файла загружается непонятная html страница.

Comment: [ссылка на исходный код](https://github.com/AlexWanderman/zerahypt_laucher/blob/master/MainWindow.xaml.cs)

Comment: Ну так и ссылка у вас на страницу, а не на файл. Прямые ссылки большинство файлообменников не дает.

Comment: И как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Использовать прямые ссылки. Для серьезных нагрузок посоветовать ничего не смогу, а так - какой нибудь github сгодится.

Comment: Очевидно, не пользуйтесь файлообменником. Заплатите деньги за сервер или CDN, выложите файл туда.

Comment: В данном случае вышеуказанный метод не применим.

Comment: Если использовать яндекс диск принципиально, можно воспользоваться их API.
Для понимания курить https://tech.yandex.ru/disk/api/reference/content-docpage/